# unserialize работа с массивом данных

Tags: php, массивы, unserialize

Есть `string`.
Использую `unserialize()` чтобы превратить в массив. Массив получился.
Проверяю `var_dump`, а дальше не знаю как вытащить данные чтобы с ними поработать.

```
$serialized = 'a:1:{s:4:"cart";a:3:{s:32:"812b4ba287f5ee0bc9d43bbf5bbe87fb";a:10:{s:3:"key";s:32:"812b4ba287f5ee0bc9d43bbf5bbe87fb";s:10:"product_id";i:95;s:12:"variation_id";i:0;s:9:"variation";a:0:{}s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}s:5:"total";a:0:{}}s:13:"line_subtotal";d:2500;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:10:"line_total";d:2500;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;}s:32:"26657d5ff9020d2abefe558796b99584";a:10:{s:3:"key";s:32:"26657d5ff9020d2abefe558796b99584";s:10:"product_id";i:96;s:12:"variation_id";i:0;s:9:"variation";a:0:{}s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}s:5:"total";a:0:{}}s:13:"line_subtotal";d:2500;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:10:"line_total";d:2500;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;}s:32:"72e0a0aebbe412653d190be7428a4dee";a:10:{s:3:"key";s:32:"72e0a0aebbe412653d190be7428a4dee";s:10:"product_id";i:19;s:12:"variation_id";i:142;s:9:"variation";a:1:{s:20:"attribute_pa_razmery";s:2:"48";}s:8:"quantity";i:2;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}s:5:"total";a:0:{}}s:13:"line_subtotal";d:10000;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:10:"line_total";d:10000;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;}}}';

$value= unserialize( $serialized );

var_dump($value);
```

Comment: Вы имеете в виду что не знаете как перечислять элементы массива или обращаться к ним по индексу, или знаете но не получается применить знания по какой-то причине? Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

"Поработать" со всеми данными этого массива можно через цикл, например так:

```
foreach ($value['cart'] as $product){
    echo $product['product_id'].'<br>';
}
```

Этот код выведет все product_id. Так можно проводить разные манипуляции с массивом. Если еще нужен будет ключ массива, то можно его добавить так:

```
foreach ($value['cart'] as $key=>$product)
```

Или если нужен например первый продукт, тогда так:

```
echo $value['cart'][key($value['cart'])]['product_id'];
```

Comment: Работает,  спасибо! А  как собрать опять в строку?

Comment: Что нужно собрать? Если исправленный массив, то так: $serialized = serialize($value);

Answer (score -1):

У тебя массив массивов. Как работал до команды `serialize`, так и работай с переменной после.